# Does every even degree polynomial in the expansion of $\exp x$ have no real roots?

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function

Does every even degree polynomial in the expansion of $\exp x$ have no real roots?

I tried the first few values and it seems like it... Is this a known result?

Comment: This seems to be proven in http://mathoverflow.net/a/4410.

Comment: This is easily proven by induction on the degree by considering the difference $Q_n(x)$ and noting that $Q''_n(x)=Q_{n-1}(x)\geqslant0$ for every $x\leqslant0$ by induction hypothesis and that $Q'_n(0)=0$ by direct computation hence $Q'_n(x)\leqslant0$ for every $x\leqslant0$ and $Q_n(x)\geqslant Q_n(0)=0$, QED.

Comment: Alternatively, differentiate once $$e^{-x}(1+x/1!+\cdots+x^{2n}/(2n)!).$$

Comment: Martin the proof you linked is flawed. It assumes that if a function of even degree has one root it is its minimum, but does not take into account that it can have another and be negative in between.

Comment: *Is this a known result ?* - Yes. $($It is rather famous, actually$)$. The first time I've encountered it was in [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=9W6GQ42BRR0C&printsec=frontcover) book.